# Error in pulling down images in docker: Status 0

Tags: docker

I got this error message for whatever image I tried to pull down in docker:
**Error pulling image (latest) from opensuse, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer**
Any idea what is wrong?

```
SUSE13-WS-mav1:/working/docker # docker info<br>
Containers: 0<br>
Images: 0<br>
Storage Driver: devicemapper<br>
 Pool Name: docker-8:2-146898-pool<br>
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB<br>
 Data file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data<br>
 Metadata file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata<br>
 Data Space Used: 305.7 MB<br>
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB<br>
 Metadata Space Used: 733.2 kB<br>
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB<br>
 Library Version: 1.03.01 (2011-10-15)<br>
Execution Driver: native-0.2<br>
Kernel Version: 3.11.6-4-desktop<br>
Operating System: openSUSE 13.1 (Bottle) (x86_64) (containerized)<br>
Username: ***<br>
Registry: [https://index.docker.io/v1/]<br>
SUSE13-WS-mav1:/working/docker # docker pull opensuse<br>
latest: Pulling from opensuse<br>
511136ea3c5a: Pulling fs layer <br>
511136ea3c5a: Error pulling dependent layers<br> 
d68d272529be: Pulling fs layer <br>
d68d272529be: Error pulling image (latest) from opensuse, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (511136ea3c5a64f264b78b5433614aec563103b4d4702f3ba7d4d2698e22c158) <br>
2014/10/21 14:58:55 Error pulling image (latest) from opensuse, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (511136ea3c5a64f264b78b5433614aec563103b4d4702f3ba7d4d2698e22c158)<br>
```

Comment: I get a 404 error with `docker pull 511136ea3c5a64f264b78b5433614aec563103b4d4702f3ba7d4d2698e22c158`  What do you get from `docker search opensuse` command?  I am able to successfully `docker pull opensuse:latest` and end up with image id: d68d272529beb08a8035f537f339c069b927f94bb6c316718480fe4714acfa56 which happens to be version 13.1

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting exactly the same error when I'm behind corporate firewall.